# Automatically apply getter and setter to new object variable

Tags: python

Ok, lets say I have a really simple class i.e.:

```
class Test(object):
    pass
```

What I would like to do is to define some default setter and getter methods
which are automatically applied to a new object member at creation time. In the example below a.x should always be uppercase, i.e.:

```
a = Test()
a.x = "foo"
print a.x 
>>> FOO
```

If I create `x` within the class I would get this behavior like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = ""

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter(self, string):
        self._x = string.upper()
```

So is there any possibility to do this without defining setter and getter methods for each member ?? Thank a lot.

EDIT: With creation time I meant the creation time of `a.x` not of the class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to override `__setattr__`, and change any string values to uppercase:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if isinstance(val, basestring):
            val = val.upper()
        super(Test, self).__setattr__(attr, val)


>>> t = Test()
>>> t.x = 'foo'
>>> t.x
'FOO'
```

Comment: I originally had that, then I think I started to over think it: *which are automatically applied to a new object member at creation time*... so I was thinking if a class attribute/or attribute initialised in the `__init__` should be exempt to the upper-casing...

Comment: Well maybe I was a little bit unclear, I meant the creation time of the new member i.e. 'a.x' Im sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass a dict;

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:class Struct(dict):
:    """A dict subclass where you can simply use a dot to access attributes."""
:
:    def __getattr__(self, name):
:        return self[name]
:
:    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
:        self[name] = value
:--

In [2]: a = Struct()

In [3]: a.x = "foo"

In [4]: a.x
Out[4]: 'foo'

In [5]: a.length = 14

In [6]: a
Out[6]: {'length': 14, 'x': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a use-case for pythons [Descriptor Proctocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

```
class WithDescriptors:
    x = UpperCaseDescriptor()
    y = UpperCaseDescriptor()
    z = UpperCaseDescriptor()


class UperCaseDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = ''

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):   
        return self.val.upper()

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val
```

Thats just an outline and i didnt test the code to work!

If you want to extend such behaviour to every attribute of an instance,
even which are not existent, you should consider [metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).